# How to iterate through different divs with different arrays?

Tags: jquery, css

I have a webpage with divs that contain different words, and I want these div to have a background color, depending on which word is in it. And the words are divided into two groups.

So this is what I got, but it only works for the first color.

```
var animal = ['horse', 'cat', 'mouse', 'dog'];

var i=0;

for (; i<animal.length; i++) {

     $("#div-position-a:contains('"+animal[i]+"')").each(function() {

           $('#div-position-a').css("background","rgb(green)");

     });
}

var soda = ['coke', 'sprite', 'fanta', 'pepsi'];

var j=0;

for (; j<soda.length; j++) {

     $("#div-position-a:contains('"+soda[j]+"')").each(function() {

           $('#div-position-a').css("background","rgb(red)");

     });
}
```

If I target different divs, it works, but the page has a flow of divs, so there are new divs every day, that replace the others, so the different spaces on the page much be checked. The are 16 places on the page, and the newest one is on top, and so forth.

Anything is much obliged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working! I had a for loop for every each(), and then I changed it, so that I had one for loop with all the each() green color iteration and one for loop with with all the each() red color iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Change your loop by this

```
$("#div-position-a:contains('"+animal[i]+"')").each(function() {

      $(this).css("background","rgb(green)");

});
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I found out that the first loop gets executed, and the second one gets ignored....so maybe I am doing this the wrong way. I tried with multiple for loops, for all the divs that could maybe be green, and only the first one is executed.

Comment: try to dont use each function and use an array and for

Comment: Got it working! Thank you for your time man! I had a for loop for every each(), and then I changed it, so that I had one for loop with all the each() green color iteration and one for loop with with all the each() red color iteration.